# MySql configuration file does not exist where WorkBench says so

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MySql. I have downloaded and installed MySql 5.6 together with the latest version of Workbench (6.2). Workbench says my configuration file is in

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini
```

This folder does not exist. I have

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
```

And inside this folder there is an `.ini` file called `my-default.ini`. How can I find the correct `.ini` file so I can change my variables?

Answer (score 1):

The name and path used by MySQL Workbench by default is taken from a template. There are several templates for various server versions and platforms with typical config file locations. However, they may not always work. On Windows however, with standard installations (which are extremely common), there are only very few variations. The simplest way to have the correct config file stored in the connection settings is by changing the installation type in the System Profile settings for a connection:

[image]

The sample config file my-default.ini is just that, an example. The installer should have created a concrete config file in the ProgramData MySQL folder for your server, which is what MySQL Workbench will also use by default.

Comment: I don't see this menu on my workbench. Is it a part of installation? If so, can one change this after MySql is installed?

Answer (score 1):

For someone wants to find the menu answered above,
It can be found when you right click on a connection instance box of your MySQL workbench home and go to edit connection.
I know this question posted 5 years ago, but I had looked for the menu as well and finally find it. I hope I can add a comment but I cannot due to the reputation;)